# IF in Where with multiple Conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to write a query where I can have either of the 2 variables entered and the query needs to execute on the basis of which data was entered. For example

```
DECLARE @A NVARCHAR(15) = '' -- Input A here 

-------------------OR---------------------

DECLARE @B NVARCHAR(15) = '' -- Input B here

SELECT

    [DOC].[ety_ts] as [CreatedDate],
    [DOC].[ord_int_id],
    [DOC].[doc_int_id],
    [pnt_cln_doc_int_id] as [ParentDoc],
    CDTL_STATUS2.cod_dtl_ds as DocumentName,
    CDTL_STATUS.[cod_dtl_ds] as [DocumentStatus],
.................................
..................................
.....................................

WHERE 
    IF ( @A IS NULL OR @A = '' )
            BEGIN
                DOC.asn_int_id = (Select asn_int_id from TPM(nolock) where rec_no=@B)
            END 

            ELSE 

            BEGIN   
                DOC.ord_int_id IN
            (
                SELECT DOC.ord_int_id
                FROM TAD_DOCUMENT WITH (NOLOCK)
                WHERE DOC.ord_int_id IN 
            (
                SELECT TPM.ord_int_id FROM TPM_VISIT TPM WITH (NOLOCK)
                WHERE TPM300.vst_no = @A
            )
            END
```

It throws an error for the first IF Statement

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 59
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.

Not sure what I am doing wrong. Can anyone please guide on how to fix this query.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IF` is a procedural statement, not a query clause. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> An IF...ELSE construct can be used in batches, in stored procedures, and in ad hoc queries.

You just want regular [`AND`/`OR` logic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/logical-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) e.g.

```
WHERE (
    NULLIF(@A,'') IS NULL
    AND DOC.asn_int_id = (
        SELECT asn_int_id
        FROM TPM
        WHERE rec_no = @B
    )
)
OR (
    NULLIF(@A,'') IS NOT NULL
    AND DOC.ord_int_id IN (
        SELECT DOC.ord_int_id
        FROM TAD_DOCUMENT
        WHERE DOC.ord_int_id IN (
            SELECT TPM.ord_int_id
            FROM TPM_VISIT TPM
            WHERE TPM300.vst_no = @A
        )
    )
)
```

Note: Unless you are very sure you understand and accept the consequences of using `NOLOCK` I highly recommend not using it. Its not a "go faster for free" hint.

Comment: I didnt get you by "go faster for free" though

Comment: Usually people add `with (nolock)` because they are under the mistaken impression that it improves performance without any consequence. But that is not the case. It should be used sparingly and only with full understanding of the consequences.

Comment: Gotcha, I use it because in the Production DB I dont want it to hamper any other queries running, creating unnecessary blocking. Am I correct in doing so?

Comment: I can't answer that, it depends whether you are happy potentially getting invalid data... read up on it and if you understand the consequences and are happy with it then you at least are making an informed choice. That said, why are you running on a production server?

Comment: https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere

Comment: Not happy with Invalid data of course, but took this path as it does save me from a lot of blocking, I usually have to run queries on Prod Server to get data or make updates to corrupted data.

Comment: If you are getting a lot of blocking that suggesting missing indexes... unless you are running a massive, complex query.

Comment: @user3550550 Snapshot isolation is a much better solution for blocking than `nolock`